# how to make program keep tract of data entered (numeric)

Tags: javascript

I need this code to be able to open a promt on button click then take the number it recieves and add it into 1 of 3 cases and be able to tell me how many are in each case at end of program (very simplified).
What am I doing wrong or how do I fix it? this is part of the code that I think needs work.

```
    <button onclick="Calculate(0);">Toddler Ticket</button>
    <button onclick="Calculate(1);">Junior Ticket</button>
    <button onclick="Calculate(2);">Adult Ticket</button>
    <div id='msg'></div>

</head>

<body>

            var MAX_SEAT_COUNT = 10            
            var amountTicket                   
            var grossProfit

            var adulTicket = 0           
            var junTicket = 0
            var todTicket = 0
            var totalSales = 0               

            var adulNum = 0                   
            var junNum = 0
            var todNum = 0
            var extraNum = 0                    

        function parseFloat(amountTicket) {

            if (amountTicket >= MAX_SEAT_COUNT) {
                extraNum = amountTicket - MAX_SEAT_COUNT;
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Tickets have now sold out thank you for purchasing."  // important to stop after limit
                 //end loop and display all data here like shown below remember to line up columns


              }else if    (amountTicket > 10) {
                 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "The maximum number of tickets that can be done in one transaction is 10"
              }else {
                   amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
              }
              return;
              }
    function Calculate(ticket) {
        //set zeroes for all values
        adulTicket = 0
        junTicket = 0
        todTicket = 0
        amountTicket = 0
        totalSales = 0
        adulNum = 0
        junNum = 0
        todNum = 0
        extraNum = 0
        grossProfit = 
       //get user input
        switch(ticket){
        case 0:
        todNum = amountTicket
        break;
        case 1:
       junNum = amountTicket
        break;
        case 2:
       adulnum = amountTicket
        break;
        }
       //get user input
            amountTicket = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountTicket);
        grossProfit =  (adulTicket * adultNum) + (junTicket * junNum)
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code is not doing anything really (there's problems all over).  Until you have some actual working code and a point where some a particular problem appears ("Here I want it to do _this_, but it does _that_ instead."), you should do your research, not ask SO to rewrite your code dump.

Comment: See [the guidelines for posting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yea "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"..... How to make the program keep track of data entered , being my question..... to have what i want explained further I would say I want it to be able to take multiple data entries via button click and be able to repeat it back.... Seems practical and answerable to me.......

Comment: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: Exactly - see the _Poor Pedagogy_ section of the article. Anyway, this is no place to hold this discussion. Sorry if my comments offended you; I'll say no more.

Comment: Please don't for your advice holds no credence. I could have posted this question with no code listed at all and it still would not be hard to answer it as long as you know the answer

Comment: And as far as the pedagory I ask to be pointed in the right direction if a direct answer was not something that would be directly offered ("What am I doing wrong or how do I fix it? this is part of the code that I think needs work.") why you are trolling me from your high horse is beyond me

Comment: Some of the mistakes you can find out just by looking at basically any example of JavaScript coding out there (like not using `<script>` to include your code). This shows zero effort of own research. I'll post the application below just to stop you whining. My previous comments were just attempts to let you actually learn something, as per the article you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYwraY)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tickets = {
                adult: 0,
                junior: 0,
                toddler: 0
            };
            var prices = {
                adult: 120,
                junior: 60,
                toddler: 30
            };
            function addTickets (type, ammount) {
                tickets[type] += ammount;
            }
            function askForNumberOfTickets (type) {
                return prompt('How many ' + type + ' tickets would you like?');
            }
            function handleAddTicketClick (type) {
                var ammount = parseInt(askForNumberOfTickets(type), 10);
                addTickets(type, ammount);
                updateTotals();
            }
            function updateTotals () {
                var priceTotal = 0,
                    key, value, price;
                for (key in tickets) {
                    value = tickets[key];
                    price = prices[key] * value;
                    document.getElementById(key + 'Count').innerHTML = value;
                    document.getElementById(key + 'Price').innerHTML = price;
                    priceTotal += price;
                }
                document.getElementById('priceTotal').innerHTML = priceTotal;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="handleAddTicketClick('adult')">Buy adult ticket(s)</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="handleAddTicketClick('junior')">Buy junior ticket(s)</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="handleAddTicketClick('toddler')">Buy toddler ticket(s)</button>
        <h3>Totals</h3>
        <p>Adults: <span id="adultCount">0</span> (<span id="adultPrice">0</span>)</p>
        <p>Juniors: <span id="juniorCount">0</span> (<span id="juniorPrice">0</span>)</p>
        <p>Toddlers: <span id="toddlerCount">0</span> (<span id="toddlerPrice">0</span>)</p>
        <p>Price total: <span id="priceTotal">0</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```